# gradle upgrade on react native

Tags: react-native, gradle

Ever since I upgraded my Gradle component in Android Studio I cannot compile my React Native app. 
Here is the error message:

```
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are 
linked manually: 
  - react-native-gesture-handler (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going 
forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be 
included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this 
message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native- 
community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" 
flag.
Jetifier found 919 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
[integer/react_native_dev_server_port] C:\projects\react-native-sample-with- 
redux\android\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug\values\generated.xml  
[integer/react_native_dev_server_port] C:\projects\react-native-sample-with- 
redux\android\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug\values\gradleResValues.xml: Error: Duplicate 
resources
[integer/react_native_inspector_proxy_port] C:\projects\react-native-sample-with- 
   redux\android\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug\values\generated.xml     
[integer/react_native_inspector_proxy_port] C:\projects\react-native-sample-with- 
   redux\android\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug\values\gradleResValues.xml: Error: 
Duplicate resources

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
18 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 17 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> [integer/react_native_dev_server_port] C:\projects\react-native-sample-with- 
redux\android\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug\values\generated.xml        
[integer/react_native_dev_server_port] C:\projects\react-native-sample-with- 
redux\android\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug\values\gradleResValues.xml: Error: Duplicate 
resources
  [integer/react_native_inspector_proxy_port] C:\projects\react-native-sample-with- 
redux\android\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug\values\generated.xml   
[integer/react_native_inspector_proxy_port] C:\projects\react-native-sample-with- 
redux\android\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug\values\gradleResValues.xml: Error: Duplicate 
resources
```

How do you upgrade the Gradle setting in your app so it will fit the new Gradle features?

Thanks in advance

Kobi

Comment: You need to delete C:\projects\react-native-sample-with- 
redux\android\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug\values\gradleResValues.xml

Answer (score 0):

React-native version > 0.6, some dependencies will autolinking, we do not need to use react-native link dependenices, but some are not compatible with autolinking, like this:

```js
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
```

Until now, the best way to resolve this is back you react-native version below 0.6 and reinstall.